# Unable to create machine in docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I've just installed docker on my windows 7 machine. When I start Docker QuickStart, I get following error which seems to be while creating the machine:

```
Creating machine...
(default) Unable to get the latest Boot2Docker ISO release version:  Get https:/
/api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest: dial tcp 192.30.2
52.124:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party d
id not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
 because connected host has failed to respond.
(default) Copying C:\Users\robot\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Use
rs\robot\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
Error attempting heartbeat call to plugin server: read tcp 127.0.0.1:60733->127.
0.0.1:60732: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote h
ost.
Error attempting heartbeat call to plugin server: connection is shut down
Error attempting heartbeat call to plugin server: connection is shut down
Error attempting heartbeat call to plugin server: connection is shut down
Error attempting heartbeat call to plugin server: connection is shut down
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: read tcp 127.0.
0.1:60733->127.0.0.1:60732: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed
by the remote host.
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: same issue i found in win-7 64bit: it starts (1)Running pre-create checks..., (2)Creating machine..., (3)Creating VirtualBox VM..., (4)Creating SSH key...,(5)Starting the VM...,(6)Check network to re-create if needed... and then error shows-> "Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start
 the VM: exit status 1"

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar issue in [docker/machine/issues/2773](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2773).

Try and see if the issue persists when creating a machine yourself instead of using quick-start:

Find where `docker-machine.exe` has been installed (or [copy the latest released one in your `%PATH%`](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2773)) and use that, from a regular CMD session:

First test the existing machine:

```
# find the name of the machine created.
docker-machine ls
docker-machine env --shell cmd <nameOfTheMachine>
docker machine ssh <nameOfTheMachine>
```

Then try creating a new one:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox <aNewMachine>
docker-machine env --shell cmd <aNewMachine>
docker machine ssh <aNewMachine>
```

Comment: I've tried creating the machine from cmd as well, and the issue exists there as well. docker-machine.exe path is already there in %PATH%.

docker-machine ls lists the machines that I've tried to create, they're all in Error state, and with the description - "machine does not exist".

Comment: @Napstar What `docker-machine` version returns? Did you see the same errors as in your question in both cases?

Comment: Docker version 1.9.1
docker-machine version 0.5.5

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a solution but found the root cause.

I had installed boot2docker and has been using for months. I had been creating all 
my vbox images on the same folder all the while.

One fine day I decided to archive my machines and changed the folder in which I was creating the vbox images. It started giving this wired error. I reverted back my archive and tested again. It started working fine.

The difference I found on both the set up was, in the archived folder it was skipping the ca cert creation step and was directly creating the machine. In the new folder it was creating a cert and then creating the machine. It looks like the server doesn't like the new certs!!!!